# CS50 Problem Set 5 Speller: Valgrind issue - Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c, hashtable, valgrind, cs50

I've run my program through check50 and get the following output:

```
:) dictionary.c, dictionary.h, and Makefile exist
:) speller compiles
:) handles most basic words properly
:) handles min length (1-char) words
:) handles max length (45-char) words
:) handles words with apostrophes properly
:) spell-checking is case-insensitive
:) handles substrings properly
:( program is free of memory errors
    valgrind tests failed; rerun with --log for more information.
```

The log for the valgrind test shows:

```
running valgrind --show-leak-kinds=all --xml=yes --xml-file=/tmp/tmpud3boltd -- ./speller substring/dict substring/text...
checking for output "MISSPELLED WORDS\n\nca\ncats\ncaterpill\ncaterpillars\n\nWORDS MISSPELLED: 4\nWORDS IN DICTIONARY: 2\nWORDS IN TEXT: 6\n"...
checking that program exited with status 0...
checking for valgrind errors...
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s): (file: dictionary.c, line: 125)
```

The code referred to on the last line is the if statement in this function used to recursively delete the linked lists in my hashtable:

```
// Destroy function deletes an entire linked list recursively

void destroy(struct node* list)
{
    // Initialise current node pointer to point to head of list
    node* current = list;
    // Recursion base case
    if (current == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    destroy(current->next);
    free(current);
}
```

Which is called by the following function:

```
// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < HASHTABLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (hashtable[i] == NULL)
        {
            continue;
        }
        destroy(hashtable[i]);
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I run valgrind myself I get the following output:

```
~/pset5/speller/ $ help50 valgrind ./speller texts/cat.txt
==10541== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10541== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10541== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10541== Command: ./speller texts/cat.txt
==10541== 

MISSPELLED WORDS

==10541== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==10541==    at 0x401429: destroy (dictionary.c:127)
==10541==    by 0x401440: destroy (dictionary.c:131)
==10541==    by 0x4014A4: unload (dictionary.c:144)
==10541==    by 0x400ED9: main (speller.c:152)
==10541==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==10541==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10541==    by 0x401325: load (dictionary.c:85)
==10541==    by 0x400A34: main (speller.c:40)
==10541== 
==10541== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==10541==    at 0x401429: destroy (dictionary.c:127)
==10541==    by 0x401440: destroy (dictionary.c:131)
==10541==    by 0x401440: destroy (dictionary.c:131)
==10541==    by 0x4014A4: unload (dictionary.c:144)
==10541==    by 0x400ED9: main (speller.c:152)
==10541==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==10541==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10541==    by 0x401325: load (dictionary.c:85)
==10541==    by 0x400A34: main (speller.c:40)
==10541== 
==10541== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==10541==    at 0x401429: destroy (dictionary.c:127)
==10541==    by 0x401440: destroy (dictionary.c:131)
==10541==    by 0x401440: destroy (dictionary.c:131)
==10541==    by 0x401440: destroy (dictionary.c:131)
==10541==    by 0x4014A4: unload (dictionary.c:144)
==10541==    by 0x400ED9: main (speller.c:152)
==10541==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==10541==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10541==    by 0x401325: load (dictionary.c:85)
==10541==    by 0x400A34: main (speller.c:40)
==10541== 

WORDS MISSPELLED:     0
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  143091
WORDS IN TEXT:        6
TIME IN load:         1.46
TIME IN check:        0.00
TIME IN size:         0.00
TIME IN unload:       0.25
TIME IN TOTAL:        1.72

==10541== 
==10541== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10541==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10541==   total heap usage: 143,096 allocs, 143,096 frees, 8,023,416 bytes allocated
==10541== 
==10541== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10541== 
==10541== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10541== ERROR SUMMARY: 40053 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Asking for help...

==10541== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Looks like you're trying to use a variable that might not have a value? Take a closer look at line 127 of dictionary.c.
```

Any ideas on where I've gone wrong? I thought since I initialised current to list this shouldn't be a problem. I tried initialising current to NULL before list but this hasn't made any difference.

*Edit

Added full code in since valgrind test refers to other lines:

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Define node in hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Keep track of number of words in dictionary
int dict_size = 0;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int HASHTABLE_SIZE = 65536;

// Declare Hash table
node *hashtable[HASHTABLE_SIZE];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // Make lowercase copy of word (so resulting index from hash function will match)
    int n = strlen(word);
    char word_copy[n+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        word_copy[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
    // Add NULL terminating character to lowercase copy of word
    word_copy[n] = '\0';
    // Hash lowercase word to obtain index
    int hash_index = hash(word_copy);
    // Create pointer to node that points to the linked list at that element
    node* trav = hashtable[hash_index];
    // Traverse/search linked list for desired word
    while (trav != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(trav->word, word_copy) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        trav = trav->next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
    {
        hash = (hash << 2) ^ word[i];
    }
    return hash % HASHTABLE_SIZE;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    //Open dictionary.h file
    FILE* dict_ptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    // Check to see if dictionary.h file pointer is NULL
    if (dict_ptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not open %s", dictionary);
        return false;
    }
    // Create array of chars into which we can temporarily store each
    char buffer[LENGTH + 1];
    // Loop over whole to copy each string until we reach end of file (EOF)
    while (fscanf(dict_ptr, "%s", buffer) != EOF)
    {
        // Create temporary node for current word
        node* current = malloc(sizeof(node));
        // Check if pointer to temporary node equals NULL
        if (current == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Copy current word into string field of node
        strcpy(current->word, buffer);
        // Implement hash function on current word to obtain hash table index value for current word
        int index = hash(buffer);
        // Add current word node to hashtable array
        // If there are no nodes at that element, simply add node to that element
        if (hashtable[index] == NULL)
        {
            hashtable[index] = current;
            dict_size++;
        }
        // Else add current node to beginning of linked list at that element
        else
        {
            current->next = hashtable[index];
            hashtable[index] = current;
            dict_size++;
        }
    }
    fclose(dict_ptr);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return dict_size;
}

// Destroy function deletes an entire linked list recursively

void destroy(struct node* list)
{
    // Initialise current node pointer to point to head of list
    node* current_node = list;
    // Recursion base case
    if (current_node == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    destroy(current_node->next);
    free(current_node);
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < HASHTABLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (hashtable[i] == NULL)
        {
            continue;
        }
        destroy(hashtable[i]);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The "track origins" output is not helpful, since no argument was supplied to `./speller` (as per the Usage message).

Comment: My mistake I pasted the wrong output. Edited the post to show the correct output from the test text provided for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at `load`:

```
    node* current = malloc(sizeof(node));
    // Check if pointer to temporary node equals NULL
    if (current == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Copy current word into string field of node
    strcpy(current->word, buffer);
    // Implement hash function on current word to obtain hash table index value for current word
    int index = hash(buffer);
    // Add current word node to hashtable array
    // If there are no nodes at that element, simply add node to that element
    if (hashtable[index] == NULL)
    {
        hashtable[index] = current;
        dict_size++;
    }
    // Else add current node to beginning of linked list at that element
    else
    {
        current->next = hashtable[index];
        hashtable[index] = current;
        dict_size++;
    }
```

You allocate space for `current`, then copy a string into `word`.  However, you only set `next` if the list isn't empty.  When it is empty, you never set `next`.  So when you later traverse the list, you're reading an uninitialized value.

You need to set `next` in that case as well:

```
    // Add current word node to hashtable array
    // If there are no nodes at that element, simply add node to that element
    if (hashtable[index] == NULL)
    {
        current->next = NULL;
        hashtable[index] = current;
        dict_size++;
    }
    // Else add current node to beginning of linked list at that element
    else
    {
        current->next = hashtable[index];
        hashtable[index] = current;
        dict_size++;
    }
```

Note here that what you do in each case is the same, so you can consolidate them:

```
    // Add current word node to hashtable array
    current->next = hashtable[index];
    hashtable[index] = current;
    dict_size++;
```

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks a lot! With regards to consolidating them, is the if condition not different as it is adding the node to an empty list, and setting it's 'next' field to NULL, whereas with the else condition the node is being added to the beginning of the linked list and its 'next' field is being set to the old head node of the list?

Comment: @Biggles-2 Because `hashtable[index]` is NULL in the first case, that means `current->next = NULL;` does the same as `current->next = hashtable[index];`.  Conceptually it makes sense as well.  `current` is becoming the head node and so should point to whatever the old head node was, whether that be an existing node or NULL.

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean that does make sense, I'll simplify the code and consolidate the two. Cheers again!